# Not able to visualize or record point cloud using openni_viewer

Tags: pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not able to visualize the point cloud data using the openni_viewer and further not able to capture .pcd image. There is no error message anywhere. Although, point cloud stream is getting displayed using rviz. I am using kinect sensor.
I am using pcl17 library. And trying to view Point cloud live stream using the inbuilt binary called ./pcl_openni_viewer and  to capture/record i am using the ./pcl_openni_pcd_recorder .
Any possible suggestion, what am i missing ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66438/not-able-to-visualize-or-record-point-cloud-using-openni_viewer/) by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2013-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are pcl methods.  I suggest you ask on the pcl-users mailing list. Information on joining is here: http://pointclouds.org/contact.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0